# I need positive modulus for array index iteration

Tags: c#, indexing, modulo

I have a list `List A` consisted of strings `{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}`.
My program runs in iterations and for each iteration I want to create a new list `List B` which is going to contain the same strings, but each of them *should move to one position to the left*. Here is the example of what the `List B` should look like in first three iterations:

1. iteration, the List B should be: `listB = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}`
2. iteration, the List B should be: `listB = {"b", "c", "d", "e", "a"}`
3. iteration, the List B should be: `listB = {"c", "d", "e", "a", "b"}`
   and so on...

I have achieved the desired functionality with the following method:

```
private List<string> CalculateQueueOrder(List<string> listA, int iterationNum)
{
    int listACount = listA.Count;
    List<string> listB = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listACount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < listACount; j++)
        {
            int order = ((j - iterationNum) % listACount + 1);
            if (order == i)
            {
                string listItem = listA[j];
                listB.Add(listItem);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return listB;
}
```

However, there is an issue with this method. In time as the number of iterations increases, the `j - iterationNum` starts returning negative values, which makes modulus start returning negative values as well. The whole function fails. I need to make the modulus always return the positive value, like it does in Microsofot Excel (mod function).

Could you help me out fixing the formula for `int order`? Thanks.

Comment: Are you committed to this double loop paradigm?  I would think you could figure out based on the list size and iteration number, in O(1) time, how much you'd need to shift by, and then simply build a new list.

Comment: @ErikDietrich Any solution is fine. I don't mind dropping the 2 loops idea. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this here: http://rextester.com/HXACA68585

Method is:

```
    private static IEnumerable<T> Cycle<T>(List<T> data, int num)
    {
        var start = num%data.Count;
        for(var i=0;i<data.Count;i++)
        {
            yield return data[(i+start)%data.Count];
        }
    }
```

Which you can stuff back into a new list if you wanted:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(){"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
List<string> newList = new List<string>(Cycle(list,2)); // contains c, d, e, a, b
```

But to test your required results used this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(){"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
Dump(Cycle(list,0));
Dump(Cycle(list,1));
Dump(Cycle(list,2));
Dump(Cycle(list,3));
Dump(Cycle(list,4));
Dump(Cycle(list,5));
Dump(Cycle(list,6));
```

Output as follows:

```
a, b, c, d, e
b, c, d, e, a
c, d, e, a, b
d, e, a, b, c
e, a, b, c, d
a, b, c, d, e
b, c, d, e, a
```

Answer (score 3):

That's one hell of a convoluted way to do the job, and it doesn't actually work at all, not only when iterationNum is too large. This should help:

```
int order = ((listACount + j - iterationNum % listACount + 1) % listACount);
```

And a simpler way, just in case:

```
private List<string> CalculateQueueOrder(List<string> list, int iterationNum) {
    iterationNum = (iterationNum - 1) % list.Count;
    return list.Skip(iterationNum).Concat(list.Take(iterationNum)).ToList();
}
```

Both methods assume that iteration starts from 1, not 0, i.e. if iterationNum equals to 1, the function returns the original list.

Comment: the `int order` calculation fails after 5th iteration if there are 5 items in a list. As for the second solution, could you explain what you mean by `Skip` and `Take` methods? Thanks.

Comment: ok, now it should work for all numbers, even for negative. :>

Comment: as for skip and take, these are part of LINQ. These two methods return a modified version of the collection they were called on. 'Skip' just skips first n elements, and returns the rest. 'Take' takes first n elements, and throws away the remaining ones. Concat just appends one collection to another. So these three methods just take first n elements of a collection and append them to the end, which is exactly what you need to do. LINQ is a relatively broad topic, and one of the things that make c# one damn fine language (compared to java), so i highly advise you to read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int order = ((j - iterationNum) % listACount + 1);
if (order < 0) order += listACount + 1;
```

for a quick fix. Although I would try to rewite the method, that double loop should be unnecessary.

Comment: If there are 5 list items in `listA`, like in the question above, adding you line fails in the second iteration: string `"a"` does not move to the last position in the `listB`.

Answer (score 1):

You solution is O(N^2) while it can be solved in O(N) time:

```
int iterationNumber = 2 % listA.Count; // substitute 2 with whatever number you want
List<string> listA = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };

var listB = listA.Skip(iterationNumber).Concat(listA.Take(iterationNumber));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var orglist = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

foreach (var list in CalculateQueueOrder(orglist))    
{
      Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ",list));
}

IEnumerable<List<string>> CalculateQueueOrder(List<string> list)
{
    //yield return list; //if you need the original list
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count-1; i++)
    {
        var newList = new List<string>(list.Skip(1));
        newList.Add(list.First());
        list  = newList;
        yield return newList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, second attempt:

```
    public List<string> CalculateQueueOrder(List<string> list, int shift) {
        int len = list.Count;
        int start = shift % len;

        List<string> newList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = start; i < len; ++i) {
            newList.Add(list[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < start; ++i) {
            newList.Add(list[i]);
        }

        return newList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that I slapped together with a better runtime.  It works for the included unit tests, and you can tweak from there if I didn't nail it exactly first time through...

```
[TestClass]
public class ScratchPadTest
{

    private int CalculateShift(int listCount, int iterations)
    {
        if (listCount == 0)
        { 
            return 0;
        }
        return iterations % listCount;
    }



    private List<string> PerformShift(List<string> list, int iterations)
    {
        var myShiftCount = CalculateShift(list.Count, iterations);
        var myList = new List<string>();

        for (int index = 0; index < myShiftCount; index++)
        {
            myList.Add(list[(index + myShiftCount) % list.Count]);
        }
        return myList;
    }

    [TestMethod, Owner("ebd"), TestCategory("Proven"), TestCategory("Unit")]
    public void ZeroIterationsReturns0()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual<int>(0, CalculateShift(0, 0));

    }

    [TestMethod, Owner("ebd"), TestCategory("Proven"), TestCategory("Unit")]
    public void OneITerationReturnsOne_With_List_Size_Two()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual<int>(1, CalculateShift(2, 1));
    }

    [TestMethod, Owner("ebd"), TestCategory("Proven"), TestCategory("Unit")]
    public void OneIterationReturns_Zero_With_ListSizeOne()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual<int>(0, CalculateShift(1, 1));            
    }

    [TestMethod, Owner("ebd"), TestCategory("Proven"), TestCategory("Unit")]
    public void Shifting_Two_Element_List_By_101_Reverses_Elements()
    {
        var myList = new List<string>() { "1", "2" };

        Assert.AreEqual<string>("2", PerformShift(myList, 101)[0]);
    }
}
```